# RestKit Reflexive relationship entity infinite loop

Tags: loops, restkit, relationship

Is this a bug in RestKit or am I not configuring it properly?
I get an inifinite loop when using the following mapping:

JSON:

```
[
{
    "name": "Test 1",
    "subtests": [
        {
            "name": "Subtest 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Subtest 2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Subtest 3"
        }
    ],
    "children": ["Test 1"]
},
{
    "name": "Test 2",
    "subtests": [
        {
            "name": "Subtest 4"
        },
        {
            "name": "Subtest 5"
        },
        {
            "name": "Subtest 6"
        }
    ],
    "children": ["Test 2"]
}
]
```

Mapping providers:

```
+ (RKMapping *)testMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Test class]) inManagedObjectStore:[InfoDataModel sharedDataModel].objectStore];

    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"name" ];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"name" ]];

    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"children" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:[MappingProvider reflexiveTestMapping]]];
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"subtests" toKeyPath:@"subtests" withMapping:[MappingProvider subTestMapping]]];

    return mapping;
}

+ (RKMapping *)reflexiveTestMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Test class]) inManagedObjectStore:[InfoDataModel sharedDataModel].objectStore];

    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"name" ];

    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"name" withMapping:[MappingProvider testMapping]]];

    return mapping;
}

+ (RKMapping *)subTestMapping;
{
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([SubTest class]) inManagedObjectStore:[InfoDataModel sharedDataModel].objectStore];

    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"name" ];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"name" ]];

    return mapping;    
}
```

I call it from here:

```
- (IBAction)loadTestAndSubtestEntity:(id)sender {
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit", RKLogLevelWarning);
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

    NSString *filePathComponent = [self.pathComponent     stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.json"];
    [[InfoDataModel sharedDataModel] importDataFromJsonFilePathComponent:filePathComponent withMapping:[MappingProvider testMapping]];
}
```

No output is generated since it hangs:
self.storePath is initialized with a file path.

```
- (void)importDataFromJsonFilePathComponent:(NSString *)jsonFilePathComponent withMapping:(RKMapping *)mapping
{
    if (self.storePath) {
        NSString *jsonFilePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:jsonFilePathComponent];
        MyLog(@"InfoDataModel. JSON file: %@", jsonFilePath);
        RKManagedObjectImporter *importer = [[RKManagedObjectImporter alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.objectStore.managedObjectModel storePath:self.storePath];
        importer.resetsStoreBeforeImporting = NO;
        MyLog(@"InfoDataModel. Store: %@", self.storePath);

        NSError *error = nil;
        [importer importObjectsFromItemAtPath:jsonFilePath
                                  withMapping:mapping
                                      keyPath:nil
                                        error:&error];

        BOOL success = [importer finishImporting:&error];
        if (success) {
            [importer logSeedingInfo];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have 2 methods which are calling each other. The `testMapping` method calls the `reflexiveTestMapping` method due to the line:

```
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"children" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:[MappingProvider reflexiveTestMapping]]];
```

And the `reflexiveTestMapping` method calls the `testMapping` method due to the line:

```
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"name" withMapping:[MappingProvider testMapping]]];
```

This is a hard circularity that has nothing directly to do with the mappings and is simply related to the way you're trying to create the mappings.

The mappings don't need to be created this way as the `children` relationship in the JSON only contains the name, not the full object.

Answer (score 0):

One 'solution' out of this recursion is to limit the maximun number of recursion calls based
on the estimated jumps, in this case two jumps.

```
+ (RKMapping *)reflexiveTestMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Test class]) inManagedObjectStore:[InfoDataModel sharedDataModel].objectStore];

    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"name" ];

    // No more recursion calls from this point

    return mapping;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to just *fix the recursion*?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the recursion:

```
+ (RKMapping *)testMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *innerMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Test class]) inManagedObjectStore:[InfoDataModel sharedDataModel].objectStore];
    innerMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"name" ];

    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Test class]) inManagedObjectStore:[InfoDataModel sharedDataModel].objectStore];
    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"name" ];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"name" ]];

    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"children" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:innerMapping]];

    return mapping;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did with swift

```
class var keyAll: [String] {
    return [
      "title",
      "desc"
    ]
  }

  class var objectMapping: RKObjectMapping {
    let childMapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: Category.self)
    childMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray(keyAll)

    let mapping = RKObjectMapping(forClass: Category.self)
    mapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray(keyAll)

    mapping.addPropertyMapping(RKRelationshipMapping(fromKeyPath: keyChilds, toKeyPath: keyChilds, withMapping: childMapping))
    return mapping
  }
```